# How to use Realm in a dynamic framework without dependency managers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, realm

I want to use Realm in my dynamic framework, but I get some linker errors and the message, that there isn't such a module. Therefore I searched for solutions, but the most of them suggest the use of a dependency manager like CocoaPods, and that's not what I want. What I want, is to add Realm manually. How can I do that? (My framework is for iOS)

[image]

Comment: Did you add both the 'Realm' and 'RealmSwift' frameworks to your project? Did you check 'Copy files if needed' when adding them? Are they both added as 'Embedded binaries'? Are their targets set correctly?

Comment: @DávidPásztor 1. Yes I have added both of them 2.  'Copy files if needed' checked 3. Frameworks have not a embedded binaries section. 4. Targets are set correctly.

Comment: Now it works fine. It was just a hidden error in the code. Sometimes Xcode's error messages are very great. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I Think  about the "Other Linker Flag" and why Fixed the problem like this see :
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html

And Solve this Problem go to this link.
http://docs.onemobilesdk.aol.com/ios-ad-sdk/adding-objc-linker-flag-xcode.html

Comment: will you please copy your project again and check the "copy file if needed" and then update  "Other Linker Flag"

Answer (score -1):

you can download Realm latest release version, add Realm.framework to your project and linking to targets, see [Realm - Getting started](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#getting-started)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be aware that link only answers are discouraged here. Links can stop working any time, so if you include a link in your answer, please make sure that you also provide sufficient explanation of its content so that even if the link stops working, your answer will stay helpful.